# setInterval при переключении вкладок приостанавливает работу

Tags: javascript, setinterval, браузер

Подскажите, а если duration 10 например.

```
var a = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a + " "));
  a++;
}, 10);
```

то и этот код будет работать с задержкой при переключении вкладки. как исправить? у меня, например, в коде мяч двигается. при переключении вкладки соответственно прекращает. Как быть? куда копать? Спасибо

Comment: где-то была тема, что хром, в частности, замедляет таймер до одной секунды или около того, убедиться в этом можно добавив в твоем коде строку `document.title = a` Тогда значение будет выводиться и в заголовке страницы и можно будет видеть изменения даже когда открыта другая вкладка

Comment: @Grundy Ага, спасибо большое за подсказку. С заголовком это оч круто. Полезно    для тестирования! Спасибо